# downloading updates

Tags: 12.10, update-manager, cd

When I click install updates from the update manager I receive the following
error message:

> "Cd/dvd Ubuntu 12.10_quantal quetz_-release 1386 (20121017.2) required"

I cannot find this item to burn a disc.

Comment: If your problem is by an answer, please select it as the accepted answer, so everyone knows this issue has been resolved(and for people having the same "issue" in the future know what answer to use).

Answer (score 3):

open "Software Center" then go to "Edit" > "Software Sources"
In the tab "Other Software" there wil be an item called something like cdrom: or dvd:

[image]

uncheck it, and you are good to go!